# Proving $P\left(x_j\right)=-12x_j^2-21x_j-13$ is True

Tags: polynomials, roots

$P,Q\in \mathbb{Z}\left[X\right]$

$P=X^{17}+\left(X+1\right)^7$

$Q=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$

If $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ roots of $Q$, then for $j=\{1,2,3,4\}$

how do I prove that $P\left(x_j\right)=-12x_j^2-21x_j-13$ is true?

I think I somehow have to get to the answer rather than just verify it,

as there are 5 answers to pick from and the exercise is probably not meant to be done

by verifying each and every answer(the one above is the correct one though).

Comment: If $z$ is a root of $Q(X)$, then $z^5=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do polynomial division with remainder. It turns out that $$P = (X^{13} - X^{12} + X^8 - X^7 + 2X^3 + 5X^2 + 14X + 14) Q - 12X^2 - 21X - 13.$$ Plugging in $x_j$ sends $Q(x_j)$ to $0$ so you're left over with $-12x_j^2 - 21x_j - 13.$

Answer (score 1):

Using my hint in the comment above, we see that, if $z$ is a root of $Q(X)$, then $z^{17}=z^2$ and
$$\begin{align}(z+1)^7&=z^7+7z^6+21z^5+35z^4+35z^3+21z^2+7z+1\\&=35z^4+35z^3+22z^2+14z+22
\\
&=35\left(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1\right)-13z^2-21z-13\,.\end{align}$$